# Google Colab Keras not reading uploaded modified utils.py file for debugging UnidentifiedImageError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory

My first SO post, so please be nice ;)

I'm trying to debug an error in Google Colab encountered while training a Tensorflow Keras image classification model on large training datasets (5 folders with 5000 images per folder) so I can't go through to find the images manually (though I already removed all images without exts or with unsupported exts).

I assume one or some of the image files are broken and want to find which ones are causing errors like this:
`UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f66303c9888>.`

I added lines to utils.py to print the filepath instead of the bytesIO bit above using advice from [here](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4678#issuecomment-640287428), uploaded the file to Colab, and copied it to the Colab Keras library at the beginning of my code using the commands below and still get the same output. **Is there some trick for modifying Colab's pre-loaded libraries that I'm missing? Any other ideas on how I can find out which files are throwing the UnidentifiedImageError?**

`!rm "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py"`
`!mv "/content/utils.py" "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py"`

Full stack trace that lead me to modify the utils.py file (I also tried modifying Image.py and had no luck):

```
Training attempt number: 016, for 5 epochs
Epoch 1/5
  9/141 [>.............................] - ETA: 1:11:07 - loss: 124759892186628096.0000 - accuracy: 0.2361
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-8dc7f89bc1ac> in <module>()
     28     callbacks=[ckpt_callback],
     29     validation_data=test_generator,
---> 30     validation_steps=test_steps).history
     31 
     32 # Save trained model

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

UnknownError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Unknown:  UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f80d4153410>
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 244, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 302, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 827, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 814, in wrapped_generator
    for data in generator_fn():

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 940, in generator_fn
    yield x[i]

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py", line 65, in __getitem__
    return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py", line 230, in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples
    interpolation=self.interpolation)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py", line 114, in load_img
    fp.write(f_data)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2862, in open
    "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)

PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f80d4153410>


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
     [[categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits/Shape_2/_12]]
  (1) Unknown:  UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f80d4153410>
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 244, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 302, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 827, in generator_py_func
    values = next(generator_state.get_iterator(iterator_id))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 814, in wrapped_generator
    for data in generator_fn():

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 940, in generator_fn
    yield x[i]

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py", line 65, in __getitem__
    return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py", line 230, in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples
    interpolation=self.interpolation)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py", line 114, in load_img
    fp.write(f_data)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2862, in open
    "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)

PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f80d4153410>


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_1999]

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function
```

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to pass an in-memory buffer, i.e. a `BytesIO` object, to a function that expects simply a path to some file (likely as a string). But it may just be a misleading message...

Comment: What could cause that? I know this code works when all images are "normal" as I've used it for many other projects to date where each time the libraries are all the same and the only changes are the dataset and training parameters.